# Tooltips does not change d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I am displaying the details of points in a separate div using mouseover function it appears for the first time when I mouse over but does not change when I mouseover on another circle

d3.js code

```
var points = g.selectAll("path")
                              .data(subset,function(d){return d.geometry.coordinates;});

                  points.enter().append("path");
                  points.attr("d", path).attr("class", "points");
                  points.attr("d",path.pointRadius(function(d) {  return sizeScale(d.properties[size_name]);}));
                  points.style("fill-opacity", 0.4);
                  points.style("fill", function(d){ return ordinalScale(d.properties[color_name]);});
                  points.on("mouseover",function(d){
                    var details = [];
                    for(var prop in d.properties){
                      details.push(prop + " : " + d.properties[prop] + "<br/>");
                    }
                    console.log(details)
                    d3.select("#info_box").selectAll("li").data(details).enter().append("li").html(function(d){return d;});

                   });
```

Comment: because you don't have a different number of properties, remove all the `li` tag before creating new ones

Comment: You want me to completely remove li tag? I didn't understand about "remove all the li tag before creating new ones"

Comment: `d3.select("#info_box").selectAll("li").remove()`

Comment: I should add this in mouseout, right?

Comment: depends how long you want to leave the previous property show, `mouseover` or `mouseout`

Comment: Thanks, @rioV8 it worked for me !!